# Trying to delete clamav folders in Trash, but gettting error

Tags: kubuntu, clamav, konsole

I've looked through other methods for deleting files from Trash, but these clamav folders are being stubborn. Every time I try to delete in Trash folder or Konsole I get this error message:

`Could not delete file /home/username/.local/share/Trash/files/clamav-0.100.0 (1)/doc-pak/COPYING.bzip2.`

I'm thinking I might've done something wrong when I moved the folder into the trash. Not sure what I did wrong, please help! Thanks!

Comment: did you try deleting them with `sudo`?

Comment: yes, did not work